# How do I repeat the last command without using the arrow keys?

Tags: shell, keyboard-shortcuts, command-history

I know I can use <kbd>Up</kbd> to iterate through previous commands. Running the *last* command simply involves <kbd>Up</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. However, I was thinking of buying the [Happy Hacking Keyboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Hacking_Keyboard) as I spend a lot of time in `vim`.

This keyboard has no arrow keys, and the only way I know how to get this kind of behaviour is by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and beginning to repeat my previous command.

Is there an easy way to emulate <kbd>Up</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> in an UNIX terminal without the arrow keys?

Comment: You should replace the **terminal** tag with the shell that you use.

Comment: @illuminÉ no mouse...

Comment: Wasn't *Happy Hacking Keyboard* discontinued in 2006?

Comment: @PeterMortensen no it's still available. You might be referring to the first version, but the newer models continue to be available.

Answer (score 217, accepted):

With `csh` or any shell implementing `csh`-like history substitution (`tcsh`, `bash`, `zsh`):

```
!!
```

Then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

Or [alternatively](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/08/15-examples-to-master-linux-command-line-history/):

```
!-1
```

Then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

Or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

### Magic space

Also, note that `!!` and `!-1` will not auto-expand for you, until you execute them (when it might be too late).

If using `bash`, you can put `bind Space:magic-space` into `~/.bashrc`, then pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> after the command will auto-expand them inline, allowing you to inspect them before execution. This is particularly useful for history expansion from a command run a while ago, e.g. `!echo` will pull the last command run starting with `echo`. With magic space, you get to preview the command before it's run.

That's the equivalent of doing `bindkey ' ' magic-space` in `tcsh` or `zsh`.

Comment: @Arman Glad to help. There's a whole lot of history expansion commands; the link lists some of them. I've edited in some information about magic space that might help with usage of some of these.

Comment: `magic-space` that is one sweet option!

Comment: Or if you're using zsh, "! ! <TAB>"

Comment: There's also the `histverify` option to `shopt` which will cause readline to perform the history expansion but not execute the command on the first press of the enter key. Which will let you evaluate the result and decide if that's what you want to run.

Comment: Never understood why !! is used so much more than CTRL-P.  CTRL-P lets you see the command before executing it -- and you can even make modifications to it.  I always feel like I'm rolling the dice with !!.

Comment: @abonet Most of the time I use the up arrow and Ctrl+r to navigate history. However, `!!` is easy for me to remember, since it fits within the canon as per the link (i.e. `!-2`, `!ls`, `!$`, `!-2:2`, etc.) Also, regarding previewing the command, did you read the second half of my answer?

Comment: @abonet Another use that I just found for `!!` is using its expansion *in-place*. For example `sudo !!`.

Comment: How can you escape it? (i.e., make it so that typing `!!` does *not* select the last command?)

Comment: @DavidRhoden `\!\!` or `\!!`;  or `'!!'` or `'!'!`; or `"!"!`. You can test with (e.g.) `echo \!!`.

Comment: @abonet's suggestion of using ctrl-p is the best answer here for live cli use - it avoids the actual history expansion feature, which is necessary for some, and *can* be used in place (@Sparhawk's comment suggests this isn't the case, but 'sudo ctrl-p' will produce the same result as 'sudo !!', except subsequent presses of ctrl-p will loop through the command history, making it even more effective).

Comment: @ShawnErquhart I'm not sure what you mean by "the actual history expansion feature". However, I still can't make `ctrl`+`p` work in-place. e.g. `echo foo<enter>sudo <ctrl>+<p>` will produce `echo foo` at the prompt.

Comment: @Sparhawk history expansion is a feature that can be turned on/off (in the cli via `set +H`, for example). There are good reasons to do this, as some consider history expansion potentially dangerous. However, even with expansion off, you can still use the emacs bindings, such as `ctrl+p`. Not sure why it isn't working in place for you - I use bash via msysgit on Win10, works in place for me.

Comment: Ack. I could have sworn it was working in place, but it looks like I was mistaken on that bit, it does replace the entire line.

Comment: @ShawnErquhart Ah, okay, your comments on history expansion make sense. One wouldn't want unplanned things expanding!  `magic-space` will mitigate it somewhat, but not in all cases.

Answer (score 75):

Most shells that have a command line editing feature
support Emacs key bindings. (a tiny subset)

```
Up     Ctrl+P
Down   Ctrl+N
Left   Ctrl+B
Right  Ctrl+F
Home   Ctrl+A
End    Ctrl+E
Delete Ctrl+D
```

Alternatively, you could set up your shell to use vi command editing mode, by adding `set -o vi` to your shell startup file (e.g., `~/.bashrc`). 
Then, for example, you can

- Use <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
  to re-execute the previous command (same as `!!`). 
  The minus key <kbd>**-**</kbd> also works as a "move up" command.
- Use <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
  or <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
  to re-execute the 12th previous command (same as `!-12`).
- Use <kbd>Esc</kbd> and a motion command
  (i.e., <kbd>k</kbd>, suitably repeated),
  and then *edit* the bash command line you find there. 
  Remember, you will still be in `vi` command mode,
  so you will need to use a `vi` editing command
  (e.g., <kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>,
  or one of their lowercase counterparts)
  to actually add to the command from history.
  So, for example, <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> is equivalent to `sudo !!`.
- For advanced users: you can even copy (**y**ank) text from one line
  and paste (**p**ut) it on another,
  so you can accomplish results comparable to `!-2:- !$`. 
  (Unfortunately, it does not seem to support named buffers.)

Comment: I knew about the emacs relation with the terminal... but the `vi` trick was great!!!

Comment: I got for `delete` Ctl+u in Zsh

Comment: This is implemented by the readline library. Further shortcuts may be found on its documentation.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for!

Comment: I have waited my whole life for this :(

Answer (score 42):

My favorite one is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> then <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

This works by default, no extra configuration needed. ^P will let you switch to the last command and ^O will let you execute current line

Note that <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> can be used for as many times as you want

Comment: ^O does not do anything on my Mac.

Comment: @Snowcrash Try `^J`

Comment: that just echoes a blank line even if I've done an `ls` or `pwd` previously.

Comment: @Snowcrash It's ^P then ^J ...

Comment: Ctrl + P does not work on HP-UX (I don't know which shell it is using). The workaround is to invoke `zsh'.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Usually not bash, use `echo $SHELL` to verify

Comment: `echo $SHELL` outputs `/usr/local/bin/zsh`. However, it is not before `zsh` is invoked that Ctrl + P works  (and then the up/down arrow keys also work).

Comment: The actual shell may be [`sh`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell).

Answer (score 17):

Sure! Since you're used to `vi` keybindings, why not configure your shell to respond to them? For `bash`, put this in your `~/.inputrc`:

```
set editing-mode vi
```

Running instances of bash will not re-read the file, so log out and back in.

`zsh` will even detect this for you: if none of your startup scripts force the editing mode one way or the other using `bindkey` *and* if your `$EDITOR` environment variable is detected to contain `vi`, then it will automatically enable `vi` keybindings. If you need to force it, put this in your `~/.zshrc`:

```
bindkey -v
```

Thereafter, use <kbd>ESC</kbd> as usual to enter command line and <kbd>k</kbd> and <kbd>j</kbd> to move up and down.

**ALSO**: The default shell bindings in most shells are the emacs bindings, so actually <kbd>Crtl-P</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-N</kbd> should already work without you having to change anything.

Answer (score 12):

With any POSIX shell implementing the *User Portability* option (includes `ksh`, `zsh`, `bash`, `yash`), you can also use the `fc` command:

```
fc -e : -1
```

See an example:

```
$ echo "hello"
hello

$ fc -e : -1
echo "hello"
hello
```

More info in [Execute a range of commands from history](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24700655/1983854)'s answer by Jonathan Leffler.

Answer (score 7):

I find I need to redo commands as super user often, so

```
sudo !!
```

redoes the previous command as if I had remembered to type `sudo` in the first place.

Comment: I really like this, also looks like a good response to "authorization denied". "I meant sudo ffs!"

Answer (score 6):

For all you Mac iterm2 users:

You can bind <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to `0x0C 0x10 0x0d`. This will clear the terminal and run the last command.

[image: iterm 2 key preferences]

Comment: Is there any way to repeat the last command without clearing the terminal?

Comment: Ah, nevermind: for anyone reading this, to repeat without clearing the terminal, use `0x10 0x0d` (i.e. omit the `0x0C`).

Answer (score 5):

The `ksh` shell has a default alias `r` that repeats the most recent command.  It is bound to `fc -s`:

```
alias r='fc -s'
```

Interestingly, the `bash` documentation for the `fc` builtin (`help fc`, and also in the manual itself) even mentions this, but it's not a default alias in that shell:

> A useful alias to use with this is `r='fc -s'`, so that typing `r cc`
>     runs the last command beginning with `cc` and typing `r` re-executes
>     the last command.

In `bash`, this would also work even if you have turned history expansions off with `set +H`.

In the `zsh` shell, there is a `r` builtin that is documented to be the same as `fc -e -`.

The `fc` utility is [a POSIX standard utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/fc.html).

Answer (score 3):

With `csh` or any shell implementing `csh`-like history substitution (`tcsh`, `bash`, `zsh`), you can also use the `!<beginning of command>` to call the last command beginning with `<beginning of command>`.

for example if you ran

```
$ tail file.txt
$ less otherfile.txt
$ !ta
```

`!ta` would execute `tail file.txt`

Comment: This answer def needs more attention!

Answer (score 1):

you can use `!n` to execute nth command in terminal.
where 'n' is line no of `history` command.

Comment: Which shell expands `!?` to the last command? Are you sure you're not mixing it up with `!!` (which has already been covered in other answers)?

Comment: sorry, actually i was experimenting this command at that time. please check edited answer. @AnthonyGeoghegan

Comment: This was the shortcut I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr `!!` just appends the last command to your current command. `<backtick>!!<backtick>`  executes the last command and appends the output to your current command.

There are actually 2 variants:

1. The last command itself
2. The result of the last command

Let me show you 2 examples:

**Example 1**

```
$ mkdir /test
mkdir: /test: Permission denied

$ sudo !!
sudo mkdir /test
Password:
```

As you see above, I'm executing a command and essentially just appending the last command.

Another variation

**Example 2**

```
$ find ~/Documents "test.txt"
/Users/<user>/Documents/test.txt

$ vi `!!`
# Opens test.txt. But if you do
$ vi !!
vi find ~/Documents -name "test.txt"
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Oct 29 2018 06:55:58)
Unknown option argument: "-name"
More info with: "vim -h"
```

Comment: +1 for `vi \`!!\``. Very useful

Answer (score 1):

There are several layers in which you can ask for the last command.

#### Line editor

The line editor (where you type your commands) is provided directly by ksh, by the library readline in bash, and by the library zle in zsh. Other shells, like [dash may not have](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21733/265604) an editing library to understand this keys (unless compiled with the `--with-libedit` option enabled) .

This work in ksh, bash, zsh:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> # Emacs mode (previous)
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> # Emacs mode (next)
<kbd>ESC</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd>  # vi mode ESC to go to command mode and k for up
<kbd>ESC</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd>  # vi mode ESC to go to command mode and j for down

#### history

The history system provided by many shells allow the expansion of some shortcuts:

```
!!    # bash and zsh, may be provided by `alias \!\!='fc -e -'` in ksh.
!-1   # bash and zsh only
```

#### commands

There are some commands which are able to retrieve history commands.

Like the quite verbose command (only to print):

```
history 2 | head -n-1
```

or the **older** and therefore usually more portable `fc` command (directly re-executes):

```
fc -e - -1
```

Or maybe the simpler `fc -s -1`, but zsh doesn't accept such option for fc.

If you want to only **print** the command, use: `fc -nl -1 -1`.

To edit, set `FCEDIT` to a text editor (ex, ed, emacs, vi, etc.) and use fc directly: `fc -1`.

Answer (score 1):

The happy hacking keyboard does have arrow keys, just not dedicated arrow keys. They can be used with:

- <kbd>Fn</kbd> and <kbd>[</kbd> for <kbd>Up</kbd>
- <kbd>Fn</kbd> and <kbd>;</kbd> for <kbd>Left</kbd>
- <kbd>Fn</kbd> and <kbd>'</kbd> for <kbd>Right</kbd>, and
- <kbd>Fn</kbd> and <kbd>/</kbd> for <kbd>Down</kbd>.

This is indicated with the front-printed legends on these respective keys as seen [on this blog](https://sts10.github.io/2014/12/06/an-update-to-my-keyboard-game.html).

Answer (score 0):

When I am using a good xterm emulator, e.g. putty, my favorite way to proceed is to select the command including line feed, copy it to clipboard and then use right click on the mouse to paste it. This repeats the command in a single click. 
This also works fine for a sequence of commands separated by semi-colons.

Answer (score 0):

- Type History and note the number in front of the command that you to
  execute and use ***`!number`***
- You can also use ***!-1*** (1 being the last command you execute, replace
  it with the count number that you get when you do it from below
  keeping the last executed as 1 )
- ***!-2*** (second last and so on)

Answer (score 0):

One of my favorites shortcuts is:
hold `Ctrl` and `P`+`J`
It's like up and enter but in a smoothie way

Here you can find more shortcuts
https://cheatography.com/gamejia90/cheat-sheets/basic-bash/